# jQuery Cookie When Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, cookies, jquery-plugins

I'm not expert in jQuery, simply i have code can save checkboxes cookies when checked it, for 2 hours

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
          $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    var mycookie = $.cookie($(this).attr('value'));
    if (mycookie && mycookie == "true") {
        $(this).prop('checked', mycookie);
    }
});

$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var minutes = 60;
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
    $.cookie($(this).attr("value"), $(this).prop('checked'), {
    path: '/',
    expires: date
    });
});
```

I need use the same above code , but with adding simple to make me able to expire the cookies time when submit from .but if the user did not submit the form checkboxes cookies stay till the time finish  .

How I Can Dot It ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to expire the cookie at form submit you can do this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Form').submit(function (e) {
        document.cookie = "yourCookieName=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";

    });
});
```

Comment: thanks javabot for your answer ,but still the cookie after submit my Form in life , i need to expire my cookie if a Form submit .

Comment: thanks javabot to edit your answer to help me again , but unfortunately    still the same issue, i wanna  note you that i use multiple checkboxes with one name and different values  . thanks again